# Maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus

The total number of maxima and minima of the function:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 (2+x) ^3, &\text{if }-3<x\le-1 \\
x^{2/3}, &\text{if }-1<x<2
\end{cases}$$

I checked and found the function to be continuous. How to proceed next?

Comment: Are you confused by the fact that the function is defined piecewise? Everything works the same as long as you take into account where your $x$'s lie. So for $x \in (-3,-1)$, it is true that $f'(x) = 3(2+x)^2$ and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Use standard calculus techniques to find and classify local extrema in each interval separately.
2. Individually consider the point $(-1,1)$ (**Note** your function does not seem to be defined there, if this is not a typo, drop this item).

Comment: But how can I use calculus here if there are three two different dunctions.... Are you saying me to treat them as one function?

Comment: @GENESECT analyze each branch separately, just restrict the results to the relevant interval. Don't forget to check the interval corner points

Comment: One thing. Why fo we have to check at end points?

Comment: @GENESECT Consider finding the extrema of $f(x)=x^2$ over $[1,2]$. Clearly the only relative extremum of $f$ occurs at $x=0$ outside the interval, but $f$ still must achieve minimal and maximal values over $[1,2]$. These occur at the endpoints...

Comment: But what if there is a local maximum and minimum between the intervals. Wouldn't that mean they are minimum and maximum values of function in the interval. Do we still check the end points?

Comment: @GENESECT not sure what you mean. Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2, & -2<x<-1\\x, & 1 < x <2\end{cases}$$ Clearly, left branch has a relative min at 0 but that's outside the interval and hence does not contribute, and right branch has no extrema anywhere, so you check the boundary points.